# disable links in html with javascript when an ajax code working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have about 20 links in a html page like below :

```
<a href="#" onclick="reserve_all(some parameters);"> <img  border="0" src="../images/shoping.gif"/></a>
```

The `reserve_all` function is a ajax code that fetch data from database with a time consuming query.I want when the query is runnig all 20 links become disable.

Comment: Doesn't onclick=return !reserve_all(params);" do it?  (reserve_all should return true if successful, false otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

In your global scope:

```
var aStandardAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

In your reserve_all function:

```
reserve_all = function(params) {
  var aAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < aAnchors.length; i++) 
    aAnchors[i].removeAttribute('onclick');

  // do the ajax call
}
```

And in the callback of the ajax call (on complete):

```
var aAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < aAnchors.length; i++) 
  aAnchors[i].setAttribute('href',aStandardAnchors[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.it works properly but it refresh the page.I want that the page don't refresh when click on link.

Answer (score 1):

you can do is in reserve_all function and on completion of the ajax call

```
function reserve_all()
{
  //disable function for all link
   $('a').unbind('click', reserve_all);
   $('a').bind('click', disableLink);
   //ajax call to database 


}


//on complete ajax call -- than bind link again 
   $('a').unbind('click', disableLink);
   $('a').bind('click', reserve_all);


    function disableLink(e) {
        // cancels the event
        e.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the neat way of doing this. But it does use jQuery (which he probably already uses for the ajax call, so that doesn't mind)

Comment: @JavadYousefi - its jquery code you need to use jquery i think you are using javascript only over here

Comment: yes,I use javascript code only , I dont familiar with jQuery unfortunately :(

Comment: could you see the rsplak response , and help me about it ?